# Python Dash call matplotlib functions

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly-dash

[Dash](https://plot.ly/dash/) is a great Python package for interactive visualization. My feelings with this library is that it is great when it comes to structure data analysis but when it comes to unstructured data like images and videos it is not so great.

As a work around, if there is a need to show images when working with Dash, I use matplotlib library. I show the following example to make my point clear:

```
      @app.callback([Output("id_badframe_video", "children")],
                      [Input("id_generate_badframe_video_button","n_clicks")],
                      [State("id_dataset_name_list","value"),
                       State('id_video_name_list','value'),
State('id_video_index_list', 'value'])
        def generate_bad_video(nclick, dataset_name, video_name, frame_index):
            if nclick:
            img = read_image(dataset_name, video_name, frame_index)
            import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
            plt.close()
            fig, ax = plt.subplots(1) 
            ax.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
```

In the above code, I want to demonstrate an image based on the user's inputs: dataset name, video name and video index. Then when I press `Show Image` button, then the image will be shown in a separated window (not within http://127.0.0.1:8050/). At the beginning I thought it was a great idea, but then I found after showing several images the program will crash with the following error messages:

```
Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 303, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/home/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 294, in execute
    write(data)
  File "/home/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 257, in write
    self.send_header(key, value)
  File "/home/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 412, in send_header
    self.wfile.write("%s: %s\r\n" % (keyword, value))
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
Tcl_AsyncDelete: cannot find async handler
```

Any ideas on how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call matplotlib's `imgshow` inside a Dash callback. Even if it didn't throw that error, it still wouldn't get the image where you need it. Remember that your callback needs to return some data that (in the case of your code) will be injected into DOM element with ID `id_badframe_video`. So you need to somehow get the image data and return it from the callback.

The matplotlib docs have [a recipe](https://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#how-to-use-matplotlib-in-a-web-application-server) for base64 encoding the image data and creating an `img` element with the image data in the `src` attribute. I would suggest adapting this recipe so that your callback returns something like the following, (assuming you have the base64 encoded image in a variable `img_data`):

```
html.Img(src=f"data:image/png;base64,{data}")
```

(It's possible you don't actually need matplotlib for any of this)